# TOTP authentication of the OTP received in my mail

Tags: email, authentication, one-time-password

I am building a Java web application with TOTP getting generated(using TOTP Algorithm) and sent via mail. How would I authenticate it? 
With my extensive research,I could find all the papers showed mobile devices authentication(Google Authenticator etc. ), my application is not using mobile device in any case, just a simple OTP authentication( received in user mail id)

OTP generate function goes like this:
OTP.generate("" + key, "" + System.currentTimeMillis(), 6, "totp")

Answer (score 2):

See the RFC, then you know how to verify the Otp value.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238

If you send the OTP value via email the server can just save and remember the value it sent.

Or when the user enters the OTP value, you can recalculate the value based on the key.
If you only send values via email, than you could also send any random string.

But maybe you want to do a more common approach - why not allow Google Authenticator and Hardware tokens with TOTP?

But if you are building a web application, maybe you would like a more generic solution in the background. [privacyIDEA](http://privacyidea.org) is an open source solution, that has all this right from the start. TOTP with Google Auth, hardware token or OTP via Email and SMS. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thankyou, Whether Google Authenticator can be installed on my window server and sync up with my application?

Comment: why would you install the google authenticator on your server? As Guillermo pointed out you need the Google Authenticator (or any hardware otp token), if your server/application does not generate the one time password. Then your device or smartphone(Google Authenticator) will do and your application or privacyidea will know how to validate this.

Comment: Ok..But my Application is generating OTP based on TOTP algorithm, so I am stuck with the authentication of that otp which the user receive in mail box and enter in the text field.

Comment: How are you stuck?

Comment: I am generating the OTP (TOTP) and trying to validate it aswell, so kinda stuck in validation part. What should I put onclick of "Verify OTP" button after user provide OTP in text box ( which user received on mail)

Comment: Validating the OTP is the same as generating. So you generated the OTP value with a certain unix system time and when the user enters the OTP value you can generate the OTP value with the current unix system time and see if they match.
https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6238#page-6

Comment: That's make sense, but whenever I generate the TOTP and verify it, the re-generated TOTP is totally different. I know I am missing something :( where can I increase the timestamp of TOTP to say around 10 or 15 mins?

Comment: You need to calculate the TOTP value with currenttime-60sec, currenttime-30secs, currenttime, currenttime+30secs, currenttime+60secs. Read the RFC. It is really not complicated!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have reiterated the calculation and the time step, and the OTP is getting sync between "prover" and "validator" . I hope I will not getting any issue in future ;)

Answer (score 1):

TOTP is useful when the Code Generator (typically a mobile or desktop app such as Google Authenticator) and the Code Validator (the authentication server) are two different entities.
In your case the application acts a both the Code Generator and the Code Validator so I would use a different approach in this case. Have you looked at [HOTP](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4226.txt)? TOTP is in fact based on HOTP, the difference is that while the later uses an explicit counter as the moving factor (i.e. event-based moving factor), TOTP's moving factor constantly changes based on the time passed since an epoch. (i.e. time-based moving factor).

Comment: Actually, in a meeting, it was decided TOTP approach, so I am kinda stuck here and not able to move forward. Could you please suggest some workaround ?

Comment: TOTP allows a time window to cope with the drift of the token clock. The user, who wants to authenticate usually does not wait several minutes (unless mail delivery takes that long). So assuming that the mail will be delivered within 10-20secs you are on the safe side.

Comment: The TOTP validation algorithm is part of the specification so you should be able to implement it yourself. You can find several of projects on GitHub if you need some hints. [Here](https://github.com/guyht/notp) is one written for NodeJS.

Comment: I agree with Guillermo R that HOTP is the best solution in this case. By the way, Protectimus uses HOTP for email authentication too as it is not clear how long will it take to deliver email. TOTP also can be used but time duration has to be longer. Usually, 30 or 60 seconds are used and this time is not enough to deliver your mail and enter the OTP.

Answer (score 0):

A problem you may run into with sending time based OTP codes via email is the potential lag between the code being sent, and the code being received.  Given the OTP code has to be entered within a short period of time if this lag is too large then the code will not be usable.